# apk size is too big due to adding images in all drawable folders android

Tags: android, android-drawable

In my application, there are lots of images, which are not just small button background images, but full screen size images also in my application. Due to adding all different sizes images in all 4 drawable folders, application size is increasing more than expected like 18MB just due to images. Any best way to optimize it with taken care of not to stretch any images in any screen sizes? I know 9 patch image, but how to use full screen size images as a 9 patch images?

Answer (score 3):

It may be best to have separate APKs for each resolution. Have a look at [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html):

> For example, you can provide one APK that supports small and normal
>   size screens and another APK that supports large and xlarge screens.

Answer (score 0):

9patches are usually used for gradients and backgrounds. If you are using images which have some information or picture in it you cant switch to a 9.patch image. If you are using 9patches you need only a single image drawable. You can further optimize you app by using xml drawables for buttons etc.